# How to convert List data type into Dictionary data in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I want my list to be converted into Dictionary
E.g

```
list1=["Indrajit","Mayur","Swapnali","Akankasha"]
```

into
Dictionary having Automatically generated keys like

```
dict1 = {"1" : "indrajit","2" : "Mayur", "3" : "Swapnali", "4" : "Akankasha"}
```

Comment: why do you need this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `enumerate` starting at 1 and convert index as string, in a dictionary comprehension:

```
list1=["Indrajit","Mayur","Swapnali","Akankasha"]

dict1 = {str(k):v for k,v in enumerate(list1,1)}

print(dict1)
```

result:

```
{'1': 'Indrajit', '4': 'Akankasha', '2': 'Mayur', '3': 'Swapnali'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` method to do this:

```
>>> dict(enumerate(list1,1))
{1: 'Indrajit', 2: 'Mayur', 3: 'Swapnali', 4: 'Akankasha'}
```

Also you can use `list.index()` method:

```
>>> list1=["Indrajit","Mayur","Swapnali","Akankasha"]
>>> print({list1.index(i)+1,i} for i in list1 )

>>> print({list1.index(i)+1:i for i in list1})
{1: 'Indrajit', 2: 'Mayur', 3: 'Swapnali', 4: 'Akankasha'}
```

But if there're duplicate items in your list, it maybe return unexpected result.

Comment: slow and won't work if there are duplicate items since `index` always returns the first index.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
dict1 = dict(enumerate(list1))
```

enumerate will return a generator that returns a tuple with index and list value, one at a time. By calling dict() you totally consume the generator, getting what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Indrajit", "Mayur", "Swapnali", "Akankasha" };
            Dictionary<int, string> di = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= list.Count; i++)
            {
                di.Add(i, list[i - 1]);
            }
```